# Creating rss feed with appcelerator

Tags: iphone, xml, rss, appcelerator

I'd like to create an RSS feed in my window does but I do not know how. I link the xml file that contains the videos, etc. but I do not know how it works excat.

Can you give me an example please because of the kitchen sink I did not understand.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found this one to be perfect:
http://gigaom.com/apple/tutorial-build-a-simple-rss-reader-for-iphone/

Make sure you build the whole project and try to read what is happening. It's only helpful when you actually code it yourself.

EDIT: I just now saw it was for Appcelerator. Check out this tutorial: http://twoappguys.com/blog/appcelerator-view-rss-feed/

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm working with Appcelerator       //////so I want a small example with an explanation that would be really nice

Comment: @user709593: Wups, I missed that part. I edited the answer, check it out :)

Comment: yes thank you I have already visited the site there but I have a lot of errors and I do not know how to solve them because I did not understand the operation make a copy and paste this is not handy and euhhh I have videos and thumbnail "images " and I do not know what to put as url

I must say that starts with Appcelerator ;)

Comment: Then I guess I can't help you any further. I'm not familiar with Appcelerator or its logics. Perhaps your getting a step ahead of yourself, and you should learn the basics of the programming language first.

Comment: hank you anyway

I'll try to find the solution but I accept any help that can lend me in my project